# C# OpenXML How to Replace \r\n with Break()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openxml, export-to-word

I have a text field in my database and it has a text with many lines.
When generating a MS Word document using OpenXML and bookmarks, the text become one single line.

I've noticed that in each new line the bookmark value show the characters "\r\n".
Looking for a solution, I've found some answers which helped me, but I'm still having a problem.

I've used the run.Append(new Break()); solution, but the text replaced is showing the name of the bookmark as well.

For example:
bookmark test = "Big text here in first paragraph\r\nSecond paragraph".

It is shown in MS Word document like:

**test**Big text here in first paragraph

Second paragraph

Can anyone, please, help me to eliminate the bookmark name?

Here is my code:

```
public void UpdateBookmarksVistoria(string originalPath, string copyPath, string fileType)
    {
        string wordmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

        // Make a copy of the template file.
        File.Copy(originalPath, copyPath, true);

        //Open the document as an Open XML package and extract the main document part.
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(copyPath, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart part = wordPackage.MainDocumentPart;
            //Setup the namespace manager so you can perform XPath queries 
            //to search for bookmarks in the part.
            NameTable nt = new NameTable();
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("w", wordmlNamespace);
            //Load the part's XML into an XmlDocument instance.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
            xmlDoc.Load(part.GetStream());

            //pega a url para exibir as fotos
            string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
            string enderecoURL;
            if (url.Contains("localhost"))
                enderecoURL = url.Substring(0, 26);
            else if (url.Contains("www."))
                enderecoURL = url.Substring(0, 24);
            else
                enderecoURL = url.Substring(0, 20);

            //Iterate through the bookmarks.
            int cont = 56;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> bookmark in bookmarks)
            {
                var res = from bm in part.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                          where bm.Name == bookmark.Key
                          select bm;
                var bk = res.SingleOrDefault();
                if (bk != null)
                {
                        Run bookmarkText = bk.NextSibling<Run>();
                        if (bookmarkText != null) // if the bookmark has text replace it
                        {
                            var texts = bookmark.Value.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (i > 0)
                                    bookmarkText.Append(new Break());

                                Text text = new Text();
                                text.Text = texts[i];
                                bookmarkText.Append(text); //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                            }
                        }
                        else // otherwise append new text immediately after it
                        {
                            var parent = bk.Parent; // bookmark's parent element
                            Text text = new Text(bookmark.Value);
                            Run run = new Run(new RunProperties());
                            run.Append(text);
                            // insert after bookmark parent
                            parent.Append(run);
                        }

                        bk.Remove(); // we don't want the bookmark anymore
                }
            }

            //Write the changes back to the document part.
            xmlDoc.Save(wordPackage.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
            wordPackage.Close();
        }}
```

Comment: In C# those are escaped characters. \r is a carriage return and \n is a line feed (newline).

Comment: Thank you, @Kevin , but my problem is that when the Word document is generated, the bookmark name is appearing together with the value. I've tried using bookmarkText.GetFirstChild<Text>.Text = text.Text but, in this case, when I have a new line, only the last line has been generating in the document.

Comment: Have you tried to `RemoveAllChildren<Text>()` in `bookmarkText` before appending your `text`?